# How to use jquery to remove duplicated meta tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reasons, my page contains two meta tag sections in the header, and they are the same.

I can create a jquery code to remove the duplicated one if this meta tag is only one line; however, my situation is that these meta tags contain 6 lines, like the first part of the following codes showing:

(the second part is the duplicated part I want to remove)

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MyWebsite">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://ThisIsMyWebsite.com">
<meta property="og:title" content="Duplicated Meta Tag Testing">
<meta property="og:description" content="Test the duplicated meta tags">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ThisIsMyWebsite.com/show.jpg">

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MyWebsite">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://ThisIsMyWebsite.com">
<meta property="og:title" content="Duplicated Meta Tag Testing">
<meta property="og:description" content="Test the duplicated meta tags">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ThisIsMyWebsite.com/show.jpg">
```

Is there any clear way to find/remove duplicated part?(Keep only one part)

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just fix it the right way? Or not worry about it?

Comment: hi @DaveNewton, the two meta tag will cause error when FBShare function is using these meta tag. The error is "More Than One OG URL Specified". That's why I need to remove duplicated one.

Comment: Better to figure out why this is happening and fix it than to use jQuery as a band-aid fix.

Comment: @user3174976 I see; makes sense. I'd still just fix it right, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution, will keep the first one only:

```
var found = {};
$('meta').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(found[$this.attr('property')]){
         $this.remove();   
    }
    else{
         found[$this.attr('property')] = true;   
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @jake, thank you for the answer, but I am worried about: in the future, I will need to add another meta tags with "property" attribute for google analytic tool, or other SEO purposes. This solution may remove all the identical one. Still appreciate it.

Comment: Just do a check using indexOf for the prefix of the property and to ignore the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can create a for loop and remove all occurrences of each meta property after the first one.

```
var exists = {};
$('meta').each(function () {
    var meta = $(this);
    var property = meta.attr('property');
    if(!property)
        return;

    if (exists[property]) meta.remove();
    else exists[property] = meta;
});
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7hwvyphm/